# Create new object instance in another class

Tags: c#

So I have a class `Pokemon`:

```
class  Pokemon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to create a `Pokemon` in pokedex like this:

```
class Sharpdex : Sharpmon
{
    Pokemon Pikachu= new Pokemon ("Pickachu",1);
}
```

So i did what Dmitry Bychenko told me and this what happened 
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Name' of 'Pokemon.Pokemon(string, int)

I also added a constructer to the class pokemon

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a very unclear question but you can try and make it `public class Pokemon`, otherwise it's `internal` by default and only accessible within the same assembly

Comment: What does "it failed" mean? What error do you get=

Comment: You are using a constructor you have not defined. Define a constructor. Or you could use an object initializer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read ["How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When you post a question and write something like "but it failed", please immediatly think about telling us _how_ it failed: error message, exception, did your monitor switch off...?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Pokemon(string name, int level)
{
this.Name = name,
this.Level = level;
}

public class Sharpdex : Sharpmon
{
public List<Pokemon> Pokemons {get;set;}
}
```

so that you can add a new pokemon to that List

```
var pokedex = new Sharpdex();
pokedex.Add(pokemon);
```

Comment: This doesn´t provide an answer to the OPs question. It is merely a comment I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the syntax a bit:

```
class Sharpdex : Sharpmon
{
    Pokemon Pikachu = new Pokemon() 
    {
        // Assign here (within {...}) all the properties required
        Name = "Pickachu", 
        Level = 1
    };
}
```